# How to Implement GSON @SerializedName I received errors in DoInBackground

Tags: android, performance, shell, android-layout, android-fragments

How to Implement GSON @SerializedName I received error in  `ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson(response, ModelClass.class);`
I stuck help me what i do?

Errors are

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse cannot be cast to java.io.Reader
>                                                                                at com.example.muhammad.try1.MainActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:300)
>                                                                                at com.example.muhammad.try1.MainActivity$JSONAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:254)

```
public class ModelClass {

@SerializedName("longi")
public String longitudeServer;

@SerializedName("lati")
public String latitudeServer;

@SerializedName("uniqueid")
public String uniqueidSserver;

public ModelClass(){
}

public String getLongitude(){
    return longitudeServer;
}


public String getLatitude(){
    return latitudeServer;
}


public String getUniqueId(){
    return uniqueidSserver;
}


//... More setter and getter here
}
```

I received error in DoInBackground

```
    @Override
       protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            //------------------>>

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(data);

                latLngList.clear();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                                           ModelClass modelClass = new Gson().fromJson(response, ModelClass.class);

                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(modelClass.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(modelClass.getLongitude())); // Use your server's methods
                    latLngList.add(latLng);

                }


                return true;

            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;


    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelClass modelClass = 
   new Gson().fromJson(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).toString(), ModelClass.class);
```